# change number from json to text if condition

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

i have the json array which i get from api:

```
items:[{
    Name: "Status"
    Value: "3"
},{

    Name: "Status"
    Value: "2"
}, {
    
    Name: "Status"
    Value: "1"
}]
```

than i get data

```
if (dataStatus.Name == 'Status')   newDataStatus.Status =  dataStatus.Value;
```

and insert value to my mat table

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Status </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.Status}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

But i see only numbers in status row, how i can change Value:"3" to "complete", Value: "2" to "end" and so on

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (dataStatus.Name == 'Status') { 
   newDataStatus.Status =  ['new', 'active', 'stuck', 'end', 'complete'][+dataStatus.Value];
}
```

`['new', 'active', 'stuck', 'end', 'complete']` - array of text values for interger statuses. you can consider extracting it into a variable of a property.

plus sign before `dataStatus.Value` - converts a string to a number

`-1` - deducts one

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged Typescript you can use an enum and actually get the reverse value (enums exist at runtime!)

```
enum Status {
  NEW = '1',
  END = '2',
  COMPLETE = '3',
}

// later
if (dataStatus.Name == 'Status')   newDataStatus.Status =  Status[dataStatus.Value];
```

newDataStatus.Status now has the type `keyof typeof Status`.

You have to type the `dataStatus` correctly, of course, or cast it as any: `Status[(dataStatus.Value as any)]` to shut up the TS compiler.